# Optional sub-package in a Composer package?

Tags: composer-php

I have a Composer package which contains a test-suite.

The test-suite has some components that are only useful for testing, and these get autoloaded via `require-dev` to make sure you don't access them as a consumer of the package.

Now, it turns out, there are some other packages that need to use some of these components for *their* test-suites after all.

What I *don't* want to do, is simply make these components autoload by moving them from `require-dev` to `require`, because, again, these are components that we should only depend on for tests.

I also *don't* want to move these test-components to a separate package, as I want them versioned together with the package they belong to.

What I'd like to do is add a *sub*-package of some sort.

This would contain autoload configuration for these test-components, so that e.g. `acme/foo` includes a sub-package `acme/foo-test` that other packages (and the package itself) can explicitly add to their `require-dev` - making it possible to share these test-dependencies with other packages *for testing only*, e.g. without polluting the autoloader in production environments.

Is it possible for a package to define sub-packages that can then be installed from other packages?

Edit: I also *don't* want to use a "hack", like actually adding autoload rules to other packages like `"Acme\\Foo\\Test\\": "vendor/acme/foo/src/Test"`. (Not even sure if that would work.)

Comment: So you want to have package A with tests components and package B which will register autoload rules for components from package A?

Comment: use `composer install --no-dev` for your production build. that does this already

Comment: @rob006 hopefully not - that would seem like a hack.

Comment: @NormanM I know what `--no-dev` is for, that doesn't help with this issue - I have test-dependencies in one package and want to make them reachable from another package.

Comment: @rob006 I mean, yes, that's the effect of what I'm trying to achieve, but I don't want to explicitly add autoload rules for one package to another, if that's what you were suggesting.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what kind of solution you're expecting and how this "sub-package" should work. If you want to have clean solution, you should extract test suite to separate package and use it as a dev dependency everywhere. If you really don't want to do this, you may either ignore the problem and move it to `require` section (you're probably overestimating the "polluting the autoloader" impact) or create custom autoloader for test suite which should be manually included on tests bootstrap.

Comment: @rob006 if I version these as a separate package, I'll have a circular dependency between the package and test-package - that's even worse.

I gather that maybe the only workable solution is to put your shared test-dependencies is e.g. `src/Test/` in a `Test\` namespace. I don't like that, but I guess there's no other way.

Comment: @mindplay.dk Circular dependencies are bad, because they're *symptom* of bad architecture. You may use some other solution to avoid circular dependencies, but it will not fix the main issue.